# makeinfo fails in makefile for building toolchain

Tags: makefile, gnu

my makefile won't finish because the command:

```
makeinfo -I . as.texinfo
```

fails.
Is there anyway to skip this since its just for compiling the documentation?

here's the last part of make's output:

```
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/dan/dev/arm/crosstool/ecos/binutils-2.13.1/gas/doc'
/bin/sh ../../mkinstalldirs /home/dan/dev/arm/crosstool/ecos/gnutools/man/man1
/bin/sh /home/dan/dev/arm/crosstool/ecos/binutils-2.13.1/install-sh -c -m 644 ./as.1 /home/dan/dev/arm/crosstool/ecos/gnutools/man/man1/arm-elf-as.1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/dan/dev/arm/crosstool/ecos/binutils-2.13.1/gas/doc'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/dan/dev/arm/crosstool/ecos/binutils-2.13.1/gas/doc'
makeinfo  -I . as.texinfo
as.texinfo:3501: @itemx must follow @item
as.texinfo:3503: @itemx must follow @item
as.texinfo:3505: @itemx must follow @item
./c-hppa.texi:184: warning: undefined flag: as
./c-mips.texi:134: @itemx must follow @item
as.texinfo:4434: warning: node next `Line' in menu `Ln' and in sectioning `Linkonce' differ
as.texinfo:4474: warning: node next `Linkonce' in menu `List' and in sectioning `Ln' differ
as.texinfo:4474: warning: node prev `Linkonce' in menu `Ln' and in sectioning `Line' differ
as.texinfo:4511: warning: node next `Ln' in menu `Linkonce' and in sectioning `MRI' differ
as.texinfo:4511: warning: node prev `Ln' in menu `Line' and in sectioning `Linkonce' differ
as.texinfo:4532: warning: node next `MRI' in menu `Nolist' and in sectioning `List' differ
as.texinfo:4532: warning: node prev `MRI' in menu `Macro' and in sectioning `Ln' differ
as.texinfo:4542: warning: node prev `List' in menu `Linkonce' and in sectioning `MRI' differ
as.texinfo:4584: warning: node next `Macro' in menu `MRI' and in sectioning `Nolist' differ
as.texinfo:4677: warning: node prev `Nolist' in menu `MRI' and in sectioning `Macro' differ
as.texinfo:4737: warning: node next `P2align' in menu `PopSection' and in sectioning `Previous' differ
as.texinfo:4775: warning: node next `Previous' in menu `Print' and in sectioning `PopSection' differ
as.texinfo:4775: warning: node prev `Previous' in menu `PopSection' and in sectioning `P2align' differ
as.texinfo:4795: warning: node next `PopSection' in menu `Previous' and in sectioning `Print' differ
as.texinfo:4795: warning: node prev `PopSection' in menu `P2align' and in sectioning `Previous' differ
as.texinfo:4810: warning: node prev `Print' in menu `Previous' and in sectioning `PopSection' differ
as.texinfo:4953: warning: node `Set' is next for `Section' in menu but not in sectioning
as.texinfo:5080: warning: node `Section' is prev for `Set' in menu but not in sectioning
as.texinfo:5139: warning: node `Skip' is next for `Size' in menu but not in sectioning
as.texinfo:5161: warning: node next `Sleb128' in menu `Space' and in sectioning `Skip' differ
as.texinfo:5161: warning: node `Skip' is prev for `Sleb128' in menu but not in sectioning
as.texinfo:5170: warning: node next `Skip' in menu `Sleb128' and in sectioning `Space' differ
as.texinfo:5170: warning: node prev `Skip' in menu `Size' and in sectioning `Sleb128' differ
as.texinfo:5180: warning: node prev `Space' in menu `Sleb128' and in sectioning `Skip' differ
as.texinfo:5424: warning: node `Uleb128' is next for `Type' in menu but not in sectioning
as.texinfo:5466: warning: node `Type' is prev for `Uleb128' in menu but not in sectioning
./c-i386.texi:608: warning: node next `i386-16bit' in menu `i386-Arch' and in sectioning `i386-Bugs' differ
./c-i386.texi:659: warning: node next `i386-Bugs' in menu `i386-Notes' and in sectioning `i386-Arch' differ
./c-i386.texi:659: warning: node prev `i386-Bugs' in menu `i386-Arch' and in sectioning `i386-16bit' differ
./c-i386.texi:680: warning: node next `i386-Arch' in menu `i386-Bugs' and in sectioning `i386-Notes' differ
./c-i386.texi:680: warning: node prev `i386-Arch' in menu `i386-16bit' and in sectioning `i386-Bugs' differ
./c-i386.texi:728: warning: node prev `i386-Notes' in menu `i386-Bugs' and in sectioning `i386-Arch' differ
./c-mmix.texi:7: warning: node next `MMIX-Dependent' in menu `SH-Dependent' and in sectioning `PDP-11-Dependent' differ
./c-pdp11.texi:6: warning: node prev `PDP-11-Dependent' in menu `SH64-Dependent' and in sectioning `MMIX-Dependent' differ
./c-ppc.texi:7: warning: node next `PPC-Dependent' in menu `Sparc-Dependent' and in sectioning `SH-Dependent' differ
./c-sh.texi:6: warning: node prev `SH-Dependent' in menu `MMIX-Dependent' and in sectioning `PPC-Dependent' differ
./c-sh64.texi:5: warning: node next `SH64-Dependent' in menu `PDP-11-Dependent' and in sectioning `Sparc-Dependent' differ
./c-sparc.texi:7: warning: node next `Sparc-Dependent' in menu `V850-Dependent' and in sectioning `Z8000-Dependent' differ
./c-sparc.texi:7: warning: node prev `Sparc-Dependent' in menu `PPC-Dependent' and in sectioning `SH64-Dependent' differ
./c-z8k.texi:6: warning: node prev `Z8000-Dependent' in menu `V850-Dependent' and in sectioning `Sparc-Dependent' differ
./c-vax.texi:7: warning: node `V850-Dependent' is next for `Vax-Dependent' in sectioning but not in menu
./c-v850.texi:5: warning: node `Z8000-Dependent' is next for `V850-Dependent' in menu but not in sectioning
./c-v850.texi:5: warning: node prev `V850-Dependent' in menu `Sparc-Dependent' and in sectioning `Vax-Dependent' differ
Makefile:228: recipe for target 'as.info' failed
make[2]: *** [as.info] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dan/dev/arm/crosstool/ecos/binutils-2.13.1/gas/doc'
Makefile:2520: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dan/dev/arm/crosstool/ecos/binutils-2.13.1/gas'
Makefile:1338: recipe for target 'install-gas' failed
make: *** [install-gas] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/dan/dev/arm/crosstool/ecos/binutils-2.13.1'
```

Comment: I tried commenting out the references to makeinfo in the configure file and the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted:

```
print-%:
@echo '$*=$($*)'
```

into my Makefile and then did a:

```
make print-MAKEINFO
```

to show what the value of MAKEINFO is in the makefile:

```
MAKEINFO = `if [ -f $$r/texinfo/makeinfo/makeinfo ] ; \
then echo $$r/texinfo/makeinfo/makeinfo ; \
else if (makeinfo --version | egrep 'texinfo[^0-9]*([1-3][0-9]|[4-9])') >/dev/null 2>&1; \
    then echo makeinfo; else echo $$s/missing makeinfo; fi; fi`
```

and got this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'print-MAKEINFO' failed
make: *** [print-MAKEINFO] Error 2
```

so I set MAKEINFO to:

```
MAKEINFO =
```

and ran the make and it seems to finish without a problem.